# asp.net Panel visibility in an Update Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am creating a mobile menu style function.

An image button is clicked and it should show the menu if the menu is currently not shown, and hide it if the menu is currently shown.

```
<div class="menuicon">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="menubtn" ImageUrl="~/assets/menu.png" OnClick="menubtn_Click" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfMenuStatus" runat="server" Value="menudown" />
            </div>
           <div class="menulist">
                <asp:Panel ID="panMenuContainer" runat="server">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="UserAuthentication">Login</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
```

the menubtn Click event:

```
if(hdfMenuStatus.Value == "menudown")
    {
        panMenuContainer.Visible = true;
        hdfMenuStatus.Value = "menuup";
    }
    else
    {
        panMenuContainer.Visible = false;
        hdfMenuStatus.Value = "menudown";
    }
```

This works absolutely fine, but as soon as I encase the menuicon and menulist divs in an update panel then it stops working:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="menuicon">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="menubtn" ImageUrl="~/assets/menu.png" OnClick="menubtn_Click" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfMenuStatus" runat="server" Value="menudown" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="menulist">
                        <asp:Panel ID="panMenuContainer" runat="server">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="UserAuthentication">Login</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I also put the menubtn outside the update panel with an Async Trigger but that didn't work either.

```
<div class="menuicon">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="menubtn" ImageUrl="~/assets/menu.png" OnClick="menubtn_Click" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfMenuStatus" runat="server" Value="menudown" />
                    </div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="menulist">
                        <asp:Panel ID="panMenuContainer" runat="server">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="UserAuthentication">Login</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="menubtn" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Having a page postback just to show or hide the menu seems entirely unsatisfactory.

Can anybody suggest what might fix this? I'm sure I've had Panel Visibility working inside an Update Panel before.

Comment: see my update also I did not use the this in my example `<Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="menubtn" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>` because the UpdatePanel cause partial postbacks and I am not sure why you need to trigger async postback perhaps you can explain \

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you change your UpdatePanel to look like he following

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tsm" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    </div>
    ....the rest of your code etc..
```

I would need to see what the rest of your html markup looks like but I just tested this with and without the `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>` and the UpdatePanel enclosed inside the form tag, and it works..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately that didn't make any difference though: still not working with the Update Panel.

Comment: @Dave have you tried looking at this link http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers you are probably overlooking something actually looks like you need to wrap the update panel around a `<div>  </div>` as well

Comment: i think we're using different versions: my Ajax Toolkit doesn't have a script manager I'm using a standard asp:ScriptManager and it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: asp: ScriptManager and ajax ScriptManager are 2 different things

Comment: yes, but as far as I can tell the ajax toolkit has removed the Script Manager? https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ToolkitScriptManager%20Removed%20in%20v15.1%2C%20Use%20ScriptManager                                                                                                                However, I've put all of the code for the image button and panel to be displayed inside a User Control, and placed that User Control inside an Update Panel, and it works. I've not changed any other code - bizarre.

Comment: that's bizarre.. glad you were able to get this working

Comment: yeah - i can't begin to understand it but i'm glad it's working! thanks for the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some of your code as example.

```
<div class="menuicon">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="menubtn" ImageUrl="~/assets/menu.png" OnClick="menubtn_Click" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfMenuStatus" runat="server" Value="menudown" />
                </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="menulist">
                    <asp:Panel ID="panMenuContainer" runat="server">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="UserAuthentication">Login</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="menubtn" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```